# Do serial voting reversal scripts run on Documentation?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, serial-voting

Given the unique setup with Documentation, I was wondering if the voting reversal scripts run on Documentation and how it works.

I'm not looking for anything that would help cheat the system, I just want to know how it compares to the regular voting scripts. In regular Q&A, it's obvious who the owner is, but with Docs, each editor becomes an owner.

It's even possible to vote on your own posts (without the reputation gain of course). What if I like editing, and I edit all the Documentation Examples I like before up voting them? Would I get those votes reversed for serial voting on myself?

Comment: Isn't this a [support] post?

Comment: @dorukayhan Maybe? I haven't given or received enough votes for the answer to be immediately useful (which is why I initially decided against the tag). I've added it now.

Comment: I guess there may be new kinds of suspicious activity in this context, where upvotes are shared. Looking at the timing ... if votes come abnormally late relative to first edits (like first vote only after 20+ editors are involved, for example).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We're not done with the reputation system when it comes to docs, it's going to be a little while until we hit what we think is the best possible balance there.

Once we have, then we can start to look at ways some users might game the more finished system, and then put some checks in place. The surface for sock farmers and venting hurt feelings obviously increases, so yeah - we'll make sure to deal with that.

That being said, I'm extremely unhappy with the current checks that we have on the Q&A end, so I'm pretty reluctant to just extend those checks to cover docs too. I'd rather just build a more comprehensive system (which is coming up in the next iteration of the quality project, which so conveniently falls around the time that docs is going to be close to mature with respect to most mechanics).

Comment: Note, a whole lot of eyes are currently on what's being earned rep-wise on docs, so I definitely wouldn't recommend shenanigans at this point in time :)

Comment: Thats Tim Post speak for "Try anything funny and we **will** cut you", by the way. On a serious note, I don't think its an issue at present cause there are many people from SE Staff scrutinizing docs and all rep from there is subject to recalc anyways.